# Why does System.String.EndsWith() have a a char overload and System.String.StartsWith() does not?

Tags: c#, .net, string, char

I was looking through `System.String` and I was wondering why the `EndsWith` and `StartsWith` methods aren't symmetric in terms of parameters they can take.

Specifically, why does `System.String.EndsWith` support a char parameter while `System.String.StartsWith` does not? Is this because of any limitation or design feature?

```
// System.String.EndsWith method signatures
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public bool EndsWith(string value)

[ComVisible(false)]
[SecuritySafeCritical]
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public bool EndsWith(string value, StringComparison comparisonType)

public bool EndsWith(string value, bool ignoreCase, CultureInfo culture)

[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
internal bool EndsWith(char value)
{
  int length = this.Length;
  return length != 0 && (int) this[length - 1] == (int) value;
}

// System.String.StartsWith method signatures
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public bool StartsWith(string value)

[SecuritySafeCritical]
[ComVisible(false)]
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public bool StartsWith(string value, StringComparison comparisonType)

public bool StartsWith(string value, bool ignoreCase, CultureInfo culture)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking in ILSpy, this overload seems overwhelmingly to be called in IO code as

```
s.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
```

Presumably it's just something the C# team decided it would be useful to have to avoid repetitive code.

Note that it's much easier to make this check at the start (`s[0] == c` vs `s[s.Length - 1] == c`) which may also explain why they didn't bother to make a `StartsWith` overload.

Comment: The `StartsWith` answers makes sense. I'm not sure if the first part of this answer makes sense to me - when I use dotPeek I actually get the output above. What does that mean to call `EndsWith`passing in `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`?

Comment: What I meant was... it looks like whoever was writing the IO code noticed that they needed to check the last character of a string a lot, so they just wrote an `internal` helper method to make it easier?

Comment: I get it now - combined with the answer below it makes sense. I wonder why ILSpy shows the code differently than dotPeek?

Comment: In ILSpy it lets you search for places a method is used - my snipped of code is how this method is usually _called_ (although it is called with a `'*'` or a `':'` in other places).

Answer (score 3):

This is an internal method that only is used in the following 8 methods in `mscorlib`:

- System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(string
  path, bool needFullPath):string
- System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.DirectoryExists(string
  path):bool
- System.IO.Directory.GetDemandDir(string fullPath, bool thisDirOnly):string
- System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetDirName(string fullPath):string
- System.Security.Util.URLString.IsRelativeFileUrl:bool
- System.IO.DirectoryInfo.MoveTo(string destDirName):void
- System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Parent:DirectoryInfo
- System.Globalization.CultureData.SENGDISPLAYNAME:string

Probably just for convenience and code reuse :)